# How to tweet automatically from the post author's Twitter account each time a new post is published in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter

My aim is to send a tweet automatically when a new post has been published on my WordPress site.

I know how to send the actual tweet. I'm going to do that using [Twitter Intents](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/intents) I'll hook my Intent to the `publish_post` action hook. `$post_id` is passed to my action function so I can get the post title, author ID etc using the `get_post( $post_id )` function.

**The problem**

I have multiple authors so need to find a way sending the tweet from the post author's Twitter account.

There is a WordPress plugin called [Social](http://wordpress.org/plugins/social/) which does this but the plugin has lots of extra functionality which I don't need. Also, I get lots of PHP debug notices when I have it activated so would prefer to code a solution myself.

Comment: why not just use jetpack's publicize feature? jetpack.me for more details

Comment: Jetpack is useful but I find it is too bloated. It slows my website down.

Comment: Also, does Jetpack allow the tweet to be sent from the post author's Twitter account? I don't want everything sent from my blog's Twitter account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Attach a twitter username to each of your authors (very similar to post meta fields, see [this tutorial](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields).
2. As part of your callback on publish post load the author meta to use with twitter intents.

Comment: Thanks Max. That's a good approach. Would the author be required to give authorisation each time a tweet is published? won't I need to save their authorisation? I'm not sure how that would work

Comment: keep in mind I need the tweet to be sent from the actual post author's Twitter account and not my main blog's Twitter account.

Comment: Do you mean if the author is not pressing publish on their own posts, and therefore can't authenticate the intents popup?

Comment: In that case, you could add an authentication loop into the author settings page, have each author authenticate, store their access token and then tweet using that.

This is more advanced use of the twitter api, requires setting up a twitter application etc but isn't too complicated.

Comment: That's the part I don't know how to go about doing. How can I have each author authenticate and then store their access token? Then how can I ensure my callback uses that token to fire the tweet from the right account?

Comment: That's a bit more complicated, you would have to to add a twitter authenticate loop into each authors settings page, somewhere they can access. 

Twitter uses an oauth system, see [here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth). Essentially, you have register a twitter application, pass users to twitter with your application details. Twitter sends back a _code_, you swap the code with twitter for a _token_.

Comment: You then save the _token_ (as author meta?) and then use that token to authenticate your twitter application to tweet on your users behalf when publishing your post. 

It's a bit more complex than I can cover here, but there is a php sdk available on [github, twitterouath](https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth) which does some of the heavy lifting for you.